# Why is my mails staying in “backlog” of Mandrill?

Tags: email, mandrill, backlog

at previous hour we reached the number of maximum limit of sending emails per hour which is not surprising since we know our limit per hour to send. However, after an hour passed I assumed that the rest of the emails will be sent automatically. It did not work that way. Now I have over 800 per hour to send and I sent 0 in this hour, at the same time, I see that 139 emails are backlogged from previous hour. Could you please help me how can I send those?

Answer (score 49, accepted):

For everyone with a new account (and not over the hourly threshold) and still getting this problem, Mandrill can sometimes wrongly think your account is sending suspicious activity.

To check if this is the case go to the mandrill dashboard and in the bottom left click support. There should be an alert informing you to complete an account review.

Comment: In my case mandrill hold it for 10 mins, then leaked it from small hose pipe :)

Comment: I've created a new account and I'm also having 4 messages on backlog. I don't see this account review on support. Any help?

Answer (score 2):

You'll want to reach out to Mandrill support so they can look at your specific account. There's not enough information here about the API calls you're making or your account to be able to say what's happening.

Comment: how do you reach support? having a hard time locating any sort of point of contact on the site.

Answer (score 0):

It should be something related to your api if you are using api to send. Otherwise mandrill sends them right away as soon as you reach to next hour!

Comment: Yes, i using api to send. what i should do about api? Your opinion?

Comment: in my case no api call in logs found, and my conclusion that they were stuck for too long, case 1 tickets gets delivered after 2 - 4 hours this happened two times for 12 hours! then an email gets delivered after few days!

Answer (score 0):

If you have just signed up for madrill then it usually takes longer time to prove your genuinity. 
I suggest you to send a email with your details to help@mandrill.com and they will resolve it Max. 3 working days! 
I did the same and they reverted within 30 hours and my mails are a breeze now!